# C copy substring from text file

Tags: c, substring, text-files

Say I have the following text file -

```
name:asdfg
address:zcvxz
,
name:qwerwer
address:zxcvzxcvxz
,
```

And I wanna copy the name (without "name:") to a certain string variable, the address to another and so on.

How do I do so without corrupting memory? 
Tried using (example) -

```
char buf[50];
while (fgets(buf, 50, file) != NULL) {
        if (!strncmp(buf, "name", 4)) 
            strncpy(somestring, buf + 5, 20)
        //do the same for address, continue looping
```

but the text lines differ in length, so it seems to copy all sorts of crap from the buffer, as the strings arent null terminated so it copies "**asdfg**crapcrapcrap".

Comment: There are many existing questions here related to parsing text files in C. Did you search first? Use **[c] parse text file** (with the brackets) as your search phrase.

Comment: Not a native speaker so missed on the word "parse".
Looking into it now, thanks.

Comment: `strncpy()` won't add a null terminator if the length you give it is shorter than the string's length. You need to add the null terminator yourself in that case. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are to be commended for using `fgets` to handle your file I/O as it provides a much more flexible and robust way to read, validate and prepare to parse the lines of data you read. It is generally the recommended way to do *line-oriented* input (either from a file or from the user). However, this is one of those circumstances where treating multiple records as *formatted* input does have some advantages.

Let's start with an example reading your data file and capturing the `name:....` and `address:...` data in a simple data structure to hold both the name and address data values in a `20-char` array for each. Each line is read, the length is validated, the trailing `'\n'` is removed and then `strchr` is used to locate the `':'` in the line. (we don't care about lines without `':'`). The label before `':'` is copied to `tmp` and then compare against `"name"` or `"address"` to determine which value to read. Once the address data is read, both `name` and `addr` values are printed to `stdout`,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 20, MAXS = 256 };

typedef struct {
    char name[MAXC],
        addr[MAXC];
} data;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXS] = "",
        *name = "name",     /* name/address literals for comparison */
        *addr = "address";
    data mydata = { .name = "" };
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXS, fp)) {         /* read each line */
        char *p = buf,                      /* pointer to use with strchr */
            tmp[MAXC] = "";                 /* storage for labels */
        size_t len = strlen (buf);          /* get buf len */
        if (len && buf[len - 1] == '\n')    /* validate last char is '\n' */
            buf[--len] = 0;                 /* overwrite with nul-character */
        else if (len + 1 == MAXS) {         /* handle string too long */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line too long or no '\n'\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if ((p = strchr (buf, ':'))) {      /* find ':' in buf */
            size_t labellen = p - buf,      /* get length of label */
                datalen = strlen (p + 1);   /* get length of data */
            if (labellen + 1 > MAXC) {  /* validate both lengths */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: label exceeds '%d' chars.\n", MAXC);
                return 1;
            }
            if (datalen + 1 > MAXC) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: data exceeds '%d' chars.\n", MAXC);
                return 1;
            }
            strncpy (tmp, buf, labellen);   /* copy label to temp */
            tmp[labellen] = 0;              /* nul-terminate */
            if (strcmp (name, tmp) == 0)        /* is the label "name" ? */
                strcpy (mydata.name, p + 1);
            else if (strcmp (addr, tmp) == 0) { /* is the label "address" ? */
                strcpy (mydata.addr, p + 1);
                /* record complete -- output results */
                printf ("\nname : %s\naddr : %s\n", mydata.name, mydata.addr);
            }
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** there are many ways to structure this logic. The example above just represents a semi-standard method)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$./bin/nameaddr <dat/nameaddr.txt

name : asdfg
addr : zcvxz

name : qwerwer
addr : zxcvzxcvxz
```

Here is where I will have a tough time convincing you that `fgets` was the way to go for this problem. Why? Here we are essentially reading *formatted* input that is comprised of 3-lines of data. The *format string* for `fscanf` doesn't care how many lines are involved, and can easily be constructed to skip `'\n'` within the formatted input. This can provide (a more fragile), but attractive alternative for the right input files.

For example, the code above can be reduced to the following using `fscanf` for a formatted read:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 20

typedef struct {
    char name[MAXC],
        addr[MAXC];
} data;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    data mydata = { .name = "" };
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read 3-lines at a time separating name and address at once */
    while (fscanf (fp, " name:%19s address:%19s ,", 
            mydata.name, mydata.addr) == 2)
        printf ("\nname : %s\naddr : %s\n", mydata.name, mydata.addr);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

(the output is the same)

In the rare case, for the correct data file, `fscanf` can provide a viable alternative to a *line-oriented* read with `fgets`. However, your first choice should remain a *line-oriented* approach using either `fgets` or POSIX `getline`.

Look both over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

If the name is 20 characters or longer, `strncpy()` won't copy the null terminator to the destination string, so you need to add it yourself.

```
strncpy(somestring, buf + 5, 19);
somestring[19] = '\0';
```